# Split Multiple delimeters (including decimal values) from a string and get RGB values from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an string as below

```
0.1-rgb(255,112,112)^ 0.2-rgb(255,112,112)^0.5-rgb(270,112,112)-default^1.4-rgb(108,243,1)
```

I am trying to strip decimal values & strings such as ('-','default','^') so i can get all rgb values in array as below

Expected Result for above ex -

```
  [0]=>rgb(255,112,112) 
  [1]=>rgb(255,112,112) 
  [2]=>rgb(108,243,1)
```

I have tried with .replace(/[0-9].]/g, '') but it replaces numbers in rgb values. pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn it inside out and match the `rgb(...)` substrings:

```js
let input = "0.1-rgb(255,112,112)^ 0.2-rgb(255,112,112)^0.5-rgb(270,112,112)-default^1.4-rgb(108,243,1)";
let output = input.match(/(rgb\(\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*\))/g);
console.log(output);
```

The regexp allows spaces either side of individual rgb component values using `\s*`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be the way to go.

```
var rgbString = "0.1-rgb(255,112,112)^ 0.2-rgb(255,112,112)^0.5-rgb(270,112,112)-default^1.4-rgb(108,243,1)";
const regex = /rgb\((\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3})\)/gi;
const found = rgbString.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```